# Making divs stop when they reach the end and be covered over by the next one

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition, parallax

This is driving me nuts!

I'm trying to create an effect where, with a page with multiple consecutive divs, as the last pixel of the current div scrolls into view, rather than that div  continuing to scroll up the screen, it stays anchored to the bottom of the viewport, to be covered up by the next div.

It's to create a sense of a new chapter of a story each time this effect occurs.

I thought I could do this using basic parallax techniques in CSS, but the more I've worked my way through tutorials the clearer it is that it's not possible. Is this a jquery situation? If so I'm waaaay out of my depth...

If this description leaves you confused I could always draw a diagram :)

Base content here, but its no attempt at a fix I'm afraid. I'm just stumped...
https://jsfiddle.net/x6t86umv/

```css
#chapter_1 {
background-color: blue;
}

#chapter_2 {
background-color: red;
}

#chapter_3 {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="chapter_1" class="chapter">
<p>Contents of chapter 1 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 1 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 1 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 1 (including child divs)</p>
</div>

<div id="chapter_2" class="chapter">
<p>Contents of chapter 2 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 2 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 2 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 2 (including child divs)</p>
</div>

<div id="chapter_3" class="chapter">
<p>Contents of chapter 3 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 3 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 3 (including child divs)</p>
<p>Contents of chapter 3 (including child divs)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please spend a few minutes taking the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for some guidelines on how to ask for help.

Comment: There are many scripts that can do this, most notably: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr and http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: Hi @DVK, OK, will do. Sorry if I've mis-posted...

Comment: Thanks @coopersita I'll check those out.